# Magento 2 reindex mcrypt blowfish error

Tags: macos, indexing, mamp, mcrypt, magento2

I'm trying to reindex my Magento indexes through my terminal (I'm using osx & mamp) with this command:

```
php magento indexer:reindex
```

When I do this I receive the following error:

```
Could not open input file: magento
```

I Googled this error and it says that I'm supposed to use this command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And that results into this error:

```
Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'
```

I looked it up and Google says that this is caused because I don't have mcrypt enabled in my php.ini, but I do have this enabled:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so apparently my terminal was pointing to the native PHP shipped with OSX.

I had to go to my terminal, enter `which php`, which said `/usr/bin/php`, enter `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`, paste `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH`, save and close the nano. Then I had to type `. .bash_profile` and restart the terminal. When I entered `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` after that it worked!

Comment: this should be the accepted solution it worked for me, OSX was using the wrong version of php

Answer (score 1):

**FOR UBUNTU USERS**

This is because your terminal PHP is not pointing to the one with the configuration. Try this command ( update command with whatever the `php` version inside `lampp/bin/?` )

`sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php magento indexer:reindex`

If it worked this way then follow this below mentiond link to make this php default for your settings.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/146903/make-php-recognized-as-a-command-in-terminal

This worked for me.Thanks @user3478148. I wish i could have upvote your comment but don't have that much reputations now.